# Can't manage to plot a histogram of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Python newbie and somehow I can not manage to get a simple histogramm of a column in my dataframe. This is what `df['col'].describe()` returns:

```
count    2.905430e+05
mean     2.732126e+06
std      5.743739e+08
min      3.095194e-03
25%      2.341733e+03
50%      5.092117e+03
75%      1.092925e+04
max      2.089247e+11
Name: avg_power_in_w, dtype: float64
```

I tried:

```
df['col'].hist(bins=10)
plt.plot()
```

which results in:
[image]

Some solutions where suggesting it to use `np.histogram(...)`, but that does not feel natural.

Actually a bin size e.g. 1000 and everything above 10000 in one bin would be nice.

Thanks, I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: Is this the data you want to plot? Or the `.describe()` function of the series object you want to plot? What did you try already to create the histogram? Where was the problem?

Comment: Hi, as you mentioned, this is what `.describe()` returns. I'll edit the post...

Comment: It looks like the problem is that some values are much much larger than most of the rest. If you want everything above 10000 in a single bin, then you can simply replace all values > 10000 with 10000 and then plot the graph. You can try to use `df.loc[df[col] > 10000] = 10000` and then use the same code as before.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I suggest to also make a copy with `df_copy = df.copy()`, so the original data keeps untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems the like some outliers made the range of values to big. So best practice was

```
#make a copy of the dataframe, so the data keeps untouched
df_copy = df.copy()

#change the values in the column
df.loc[df[col] > 10000] = 10000

#the print it as usual
df['col'].hist(bins=10)
plt.plot()
```